# Can I by-pass In-App Purchasing?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have  an online store, and, for esthetic and technical reasons, I want to offer my customers an iPhone app.
Does Apple allow me to have a 'buy now' button or a similar purchasing method, without using the InApp Purchasing mechanism, in order to have a direct transaction between me and the customer, rather than through Apple?
Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You can do this.  Take a look at Amazon.com's app for an example.  In app purchases just make it easier to charge people small amounts.

Comment: Thanks. You're right. I should have been able to have figured this out on my own.